# Isn't HTTPS supposed to encrypt network traffic?

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, https

I have succeeded in publishing a website in HTTPS through IIS using this tutorial:

http://www.iis.net/learn/manage/configuring-security/how-to-set-up-ssl-on-iis

Now, even though the digital certificate is not valid since it was issued by my computer, the website supposedly uses HTTPS.  However, after I log-into an account, I am still able to see the form data entered using Google Chrome developer tools.

Why is this happening?  Isn't HTTPS supposed to encrypt network traffic?  How can I solve this problem please?

Comment: You are looking at data that your browser decrypted for you. It is encrypted between your browser and the web server.

Comment: @DigitalD Thank you for your response.  The aim of this exercise is to demonstrate that HTTPS truly encrypts network traffic.  How can I intercept the username and password as they are being sent back to the web server?  I tried using WireShark but had problems in identifying where this information is stored in the packets.

Comment: That's the whole point.  Even the "username" and "password" key names themselves are encrypted.  It's not just encrypting the values.  That's why you can't find it in the packets.

Comment: @David No, if I use it without HTTPS, I still can't find the username and password keynames.

Comment: Use Fiddler or Wireshark to observe network traffic

Comment: I tried using Wireshark but it does not allow you to monitor localhost traffic (which is the one I need).  I downloaded a program called RawCap which is supposed to monitor localhost traffic, however it is giving me an error on my machine and there isn't good support for it :s

Comment: I used Fiddler and it worked like a charm :)  Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The browser is likely doing some work for you in decrypting it. Try using a tool like Fiddler (http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) to grab network traffic outside the browser environment. Fiddler also allows you to decrypt HTTPS traffic, but it's not enabled by default.

Answer (score 0):

It gets encrypted by the secure sockets layer (SSL) before it enters the transport layer. What you see in f12 tool in a browser is what gets sent to the SSL layer. The traffic that gets sent over the wire is captured by tools like fiddler and wireshark.